# I need to get the gain based on an equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have the following equations:
$\eta = \frac{(2y+x)\times \log_2(\sqrt{m})}{y\times \log_2 (m)}$

I think the gain of the above equation is supposed to be $x\times \log_2(\sqrt{m})$, is it correct??  but I don’t know how  I can calculate it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I properly grasp the idea you want to achieve:

$$
\frac{(2y + x)\times \log_{2}{(\sqrt{m})}}{y \times \log_2{(m)}} = \frac{2y\times\log_{2}{(\sqrt{m})} + x\times\log_{2}{(\sqrt{m})}}{y \times \log_2{(m)}} = \frac{2y\times\log_{2}{(m^{\frac{1}{2}})} + x\times\log_{2}{(m^{\frac{1}{2}})}}{y \times \log_2{(m)}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}\times2y\times\log_{2}{(m)} + x\times\log_{2}{(m^{\frac{1}{2}})}}{y \times \log_2{(m)}} = \frac{y\times\log_{2}{(m)} + x\times\log_{2}{(m^{\frac{1}{2}})}}{y \times \log_2{(m)}} = \frac{y\times\log_{2}{(m)}}{y\times\log_{2}{(m)}} + \frac{x\times\log_{2}{(m^{\frac{1}{2}})}}{y\times\log_{2}{(m)}} = 1 + \frac{\frac{1}{2}x\times\log_{2}{(m)}}{y\times\log_{2}{(m)}} = 1 + \frac{x}{2y}
$$

Comment: Again,I didn't get how did you get the last part ? .. I mean this part: $\frac{y\times log_2(m) + x \times log_2(\sqrt{m})}{ylog_2\times (m))} = x\times log_2(m) $

Comment: ooops, I admitted a mistake. My fault, sorry. Fixed it. Are you sure that the answer is the correct one. I've checked it with WolframAlpha, it tells the [same](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%282y+%2B+x%29*log_2%28sqrt%28m%29%29%29%2F%28y*log_2%28m%29%29)